# Nlog: How to output Nested Diagnostics Context value to a log file?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nlog

I can't find an example on how do I modify my config file so that I can output the string passed to Nested Diagnostics Context.

Here is the C# code:

```
using (NLog.NestedDiagnosticsContext.Push(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()))
{
//some logging
}
```

and this is the nLog entry in web.config (not sure how to modify this):

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- make sure to set 'Copy To Output Directory' option for this file -->
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="somepath\\logfile.txt" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just figured it out. Found an exmaple for MDC. Just  tweaked it a bit for NDC. Here's the updated config:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

      <variable name="mycontext" value="${ndc:item=mycontext} -  ${longdate} -  ${message} "/>
      <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="somepath\\logfile.txt" layout="${mycontext}"/>
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Comment: not marking my answer as accepted right away..maybe there is a better way to do this..not sure..we will see..

Comment: Except I don't think you need the item=mycontext, just ${ndc} should be fine.

Comment: See [NDC-Layout-Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NDC-Layout-Renderer). The configuration has 3 optional parameters: `${ndc:bottomFrames=Integer:topFrames=Integer:separator=String}`